# Всё работает корректно, НО вызывает ошибку "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру помесь Hearthstone и шахмат для освоению unity и вот дошёл до этапа когда начинается очередь другого игрока ходить.

Реализовано с помощью общего скрипта и глобальной переменной, когда глобальная переменная true то у первого включается скрипт у второго выключается и при false наоборот, всё работает корректно но каждый тик вызывает ошибку:
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Код:

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (CurrentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

        if(playerChange.player == true) 
            ChangeCardTwoPlayer();

        else if(playerChange.player == false) 
            ChangeCardOnePlayer();

    }



    public void ChangeCardTwoPlayer() 
    {
        if (gameObject.tag == "Card")
            gameObject.GetComponent<MoveCard>().enabled = false;

        else if(gameObject.tag == "CardFrag") 
            gameObject.GetComponent<MoveCard>().enabled = true;
    }

    public void ChangeCardOnePlayer()
    {
        if (gameObject.tag == "Card")
            gameObject.GetComponent<MoveCard>().enabled = true;

        else if (gameObject.tag == "CardFrag")
            gameObject.GetComponent<MoveCard>().enabled = false;
    }
```